# Does TLS rotate the shared secret periodically?

Tags: encryption, tls, key-management

After the initial shared secret is agreed upon between the client an server through the TLS handshake does the shared secret get rotated periodically ?

Comment: I think the following quote from http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/server-to-server-encryption-key-rotation-over-the-air-can-it-improve-security will answer this: "for the truly paranoid who wants to get a warm fuzzy feeling of safety out of ritual cryptographic incantations, you can just negotiate a new handshake over an existing session, at any time you want."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client or the server may request a renegotiation at any time.  That renegotiation would include a new shared secret.

The Server can send a [Hello Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.1) to trigger renegotiation (emphasis mine):

> The HelloRequest message MAY be sent by the server at any time.
>
> Meaning of this message:
>
> **HelloRequest is a simple notification that the client should begin the
> negotiation process anew.**  In response, the client should send a
> ClientHello message when convenient.

To quote [RFC 5246 on Client Hello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) (empasis mine):

> When a client first connects to a server, it is required to send the
> ClientHello as its first message.  The client can also send a
> ClientHello in response to a HelloRequest **or on its own initiative in
> order to renegotiate the security parameters in an existing
> connection.**

How likely an application is to request renegotiation is going to vary, but (unscientifically) I expect the answer is "most won't ask."  But it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Between a single client and server, the "shared secret" (mastersecret) will have last for the session.

Session Resumption **may be allowed** via [Session IDs as described in RFC5247 and RFC4346](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-F.1.4) or [Transport Layer Security (TLS) Session Resumption without Server-Side State is described in RFC 5077](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077#section-5.6) allows The ticket lifetime may be longer than the 24-hour lifetime recommended in [RFC4346]

RFC5247 (obsoletes RFC4346 but they say the same thing) states: "An upper limit of 24 hours is suggested for session ID lifetimes"

-jim