# What is the purpose of derivation of encryption and authorization keys from master key?

Tags: aes, authorization, hmac

We're using AES-CBC and HMAC to encrypt and authenticate our messages (using encrypt-then-authenticate method).

Sometimes I see solutions (like [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/7042)) which are deriving encryption and authorization keys from single AES master key:

K<sub>enc</sub> = AES(K<sub>master</sub>, P + "1")

K<sub>auth</sub> = AES(K<sub>master</sub>, P + "2")

**Questions**

Is it somehow improves security (in case if P and derivation algorithm is know to attacker)? If so, does deriving K<sub>enc</sub> from K<sub>master</sub> is really a necessary step?

Comment: See [Why can't I use the same key for encryption and MAC?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37880/why-cant-i-use-the-same-key-for-encryption-and-mac). In short for this specific combination it's only about good style, in other combinations using the same key for both can be fatal.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks! That mostly answers my question, but is specifically this approach (in my question) valid for a such purpose?

Comment: If your approach is valid depends on the details. What exactly you mean by AES, what P is,... There are certainly similar constructions for deriving key (e.g. GCM derives the MAC key by encryption a specific block) I recommend using HKDF instead, which is a similar construction but using HMAC as building block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same key for two distinct algorithms incurs the risk of interactions. An extreme example is when you use both AES/CBC for encryption and CBC-MAC as MAC algorithm: if you use the same key for both, then it is pretty obvious that the MAC can be trivially worked around. For AES/CBC + HMAC, the *gut feeling* of most cryptographers is that the two algorithms are sufficiently "different" from each other that these interactions do not occur, but putting a precise, mathematical definition under that term looks challenging.

Basically, this is untrodden territory, so don't do it. Deriving an encryption key and a MAC key from a given master key, using a [Key Derivation Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), is the cautious and safe method: it ensures that no deadly interaction may occur. Since you have some HMAC code, use [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) for such derivation: it is easy to implement, and has received the blessing of many cryptographers.

**Alternatively**, you may want to ditch both CBC and HMAC, and instead use an [authenticated encryption mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) which combines encryption and MAC with the same key. These are specialized modes where interactions have been thoroughly analysed, and all nasty details worked out. [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) and [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) are usable without legal hassle, and are fine; GCM is also a NIST standard and is beginning to be widely used (e.g. as part of [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288)).