# Recovery of files from a zip containing a directory (unencrypted) and 3 files (encrypred - ZipCrypto Deflate), possibe use of bkcrack?

Tags: encryption, password-cracking, file-encryption, zip

I have a zip file, `Example.zip` consisting of a directory `Example` and three files *.dat. I can see the names of all 3 files. The dat files are encrypted (ZipCrypto Deflate). I'm interested to know if I can use [bkcrack](https://github.com/kimci86/bkcrack), and am aware of the required:

> at least 12 bytes of contiguous plaintext.

My system has a modern 6c/12t CPU, and an older GPU.

1. Can I use anything about the directory or filenames themselves for the required plaintext?
2. If 1 is not possible what hints/course of action can I take to derive the 12 (or more) bytes.

I just need the files.