# Using GPG or PGP for symmetric database encryption/decryption in c#

Tags: cryptography, encryption, .net, aes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using GPG or PGP for symmetric database encryption/decryption in c#](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/using-gpg-or-pgp-for-symmetric-database-encryption-decryption-in-c)

I am looking to symmetrically encrypt/decrypt information in a database. This info consists of short pieces of information, which need to be individually encrypted when a specific method is called.

I have been researching using AES_256 in GCM mode but keep coming across the recommendation that I should not "roll my own cryptography protocol":

- [Lessons learned and misconceptions regarding encryption and cryptology](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology)
- [AES encryption of files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453724/aes-encryption-of-files-with-python)

I need to actually incorporate the encryption/decryption in code.

Can I viably use GPG or PGP to encrypt/decrypt and if so how?

If not, any suggestions as to the best library to use for AES in GCM would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I received an answer to the other version of my question. The answer is that I cannot use PGP,GPG or any other permutation of the letters P and G in order to solve my problem.

I am using the BouncyCastle version of GCM.

Comment: See: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-can-i-use-asymmetric-encryption-such-as-rsa-to-encrypt-an-arbitrary-length