# Security concerns about my webapp

Tags: encryption, webserver, cookies, risk-management

I read though OWASP very carefully, but I am not sure about some parts of my website.

1. I am using jbcrypt on my website. It stores the salt in the hash itself something like this hash+salt. I read somewhere that I should store the salt on a different database otherwise I would be vulnerable to rainbowtables again.
2. My framework is very new (Play! framework 2.x) and I have to do some cookie management. The framework offers signed sessions. However those "sessions" are no sessions they are only SessionCookies. Also I had to sign the cookies by myself.

The session cookie vanishes after the user closes his browser and I need a more permanent solution.

What i did:

If the user succesfully signs in:

- I create a random string  and put in it my Cache `randomstring -> user`
- I hash the random string an put it in a cookie.
- Now if the user has a valid cookie, I will create a "session" from the cookie.

I am not 100% sure if this is correct, but this is what I thought would be correct.

Ressource : [Is this approach of securing cookie secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17073/is-this-approach-of-securing-cookie-secure) and www.OWASP.com

3. Now this part could be dangerous. I have a config-file in my sourcecode -> All passwords a stored in the same place.

I couldn't find anything about this. Where should I store those credentials like AWS-credential, db passwords, mail password ...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, this is not true, refer to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt/17435#17435) excellent answer for more details.
2. Can't comment on this as I have never used the framework before. Are you sure there isn't a way to set the expiry timing of the session cookie using the framework itself?
3. The config file should be stored outside the web root. See my answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/is-it-secure-to-centralize-database-information/15663#15663). The directory where it is stored should be adequately secured of course. Proper file permissions should be enforced.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no such thing :(. Thank you very much you helped me a lot.

Comment: The way you are using cookies is insecure and (unless you also maintain a copy of the hash in the database) innefficient. Why generate a hash of a random value?

Comment: I guess I didn't want the user to see the token. What do I have to do to make it secure?

Answer (score 3):

Of course Terry's advice for keeping configs outside the webroot is proper for PHP, however it doesn't fit the Play configuration.

For more details check [cross-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12290415/1066240) on the Stack

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Considering your framework has that file, yeah it is the safest way to do it.