# Signing data bigger than allowed RSA Block size?

Tags: cryptography, encryption

I've enountered a small problem while implementing a modified version of the 
[Station-to-Station protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol) (STS). Say we have two principals A and B, where both of them knows the other's public key:

1. A->B: Ta (DH public value)
2. B->A: Tb, SigB(Tb,Ta,A)
3. A->B: SigA(Ta,Tb,B)

For the second protocol message, I want to encrypt (using my private key) some data using public key encryption (e.g. RSA); and as STS is a key agreement protocol used for establishing a secret key, symmetric encryption such as AES or 3DES cannot be used.

Furthermore, I thought of just hashing the data to some fixed size (using e.g. SHA-1) and then signing it; however that will not work either, since the other party must be able to extract the different parts of the signed message for some later verification check.

In case I was unclear: `SigB(Tb,Ta,A)` where `SigB` means signing using private key B, and I must be able to retrieve Ta, Tb and A.

Is there some other way besides chopping up the data into blocks and then signing each such block (ECB, which is vulnerable to crypto analysis)?

Here's the code that generates the `DHparamspec`.

```
protected AlgorithmParameterSpec generateParameters() {
    DHParameterSpec spec = null;
    try {
        AlgorithmParameterGenerator apg = AlgorithmParameterGenerator
                .getInstance("DH");
        apg.init(1024);
        AlgorithmParameters algParam = apg.generateParameters();
        spec = (DHParameterSpec)algParam
                .getParameterSpec(DHParameterSpec.class);


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return spec; // something went wrong
}
```

And the code that generates the DH pair.

```
kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
            keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH", "BC");
            keyGen.initialize(paramSpec);

            keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

            kAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
            kAgreement.init(keyPair.getPrivate());
```

Answer (score 4):

Woah.  This is a bit of a mess.  Let's go through this a small step at a time.

First off: You should not be designing or implementing your own crypto protocol.  Please don't take this personally, but: you aren't qualified.  And, even those who are qualified try hard to avoid doing this, because it is so easy to make subtle mistakes.  [Don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2210/971).

Instead, you should be using TLS.  Just use it; it is well-vetted, there are many implementations widely available, and it solves your problem.  There's no good reason to implement something else, and every reason to avoid doing so.  It has taken many years, and countless person-decades of expert time, to iron out the wrinkles and security problems in TLS.  You simply cannot afford to do that for your own protocol and your own code.  You shouldn't even try: you should re-use the effort that's already been put into TLS.

Use TLS.  Problem solved.  Now you can spend your time on something more useful!

---

(To answer the question you actually asked, if you want to sign a long message, the standard method is to hash it first with a collision-resistant hash and sign the hash.  Indeed, this technique is already baked into every public-key signature scheme I've ever seen, so you don't actually need to do anything special: they already do the hashing.  [I certainly hope you aren't trying to do raw RSA signature without any padding; that's horribly insecure.]  I couldn't make any sense of your explanation you can't just use the standard digital signature algorithms; I suspect you may have confused yourself or gotten yourself twisted in knots or something.  But in any case, this is all irrelevant: you should not be designing or implementing crypto at this level of abstraction.  The best way to answer your question is to un-ask the question and point you in a different direction.)

Comment: What you are saying is indeed valid, however, for my project (part of my BSc thesis) the complexity of TLS becomes somehow excessive. Performance wise, we should also benefit from not using TLS.

Thanks, I went with the method of hashing the message, using SHA-1, before signing. How stupid of me not to think of it earlier.

Comment: Implementing a [known protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol) isn't quite rolling one's own crypto.

Comment: @Gilles, implementing a known protocol yourself is not a good idea, if you can avoid it.  It introduces unnecessary risk.  It's too easy to make implementation errors -- and there are oh so many of them possible -- that compromise security without you realizing it.  TLS implementations have had dozens of such issues, which have been gradually ironed out over time.  Even if you're an expert, you should expect that anything you build yourself will have a similar number of problems -- but you won't have the benefit of public review to help you find them.

Comment: @me_L_coding, Happy learning in your thesis project!  This is a fun area to learn about.   It seems to me there's two ways you can think about your BSc project.  One way is to say, no one will ever use it, so it doesn't matter whether it's secure.  In that case, you can ignore everything I wrote.  The other way is to say, I want to learn the right way to do it in practice, so let's pretend this is for real, not just a toy.  In that case, I think my answer applies.  P.S. I think your intuitions about the performance of TLS may not be accurate.

Comment: Since the thesis, partially, is about securing a communication channel between two parties; thus, it matters whether it's secure or not. As im programming in java, my first thought was to use the SecureSocket class (uses TLS). However, my supervisor mentioned that due to complexity of TLS (for our simple communication setup), implementing the STS protocol was a good idea..

Comment: @me_L_coding, as a supervisor myself, perhaps I can get away with the following observation: sometimes supervisors say slightly silly things. :-)  Using an existing TLS implementation (e.g., [JSSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)) is a lot less complex than implementing the STS protocol afresh.  On the other hand, learning how to implement crypto primitives and STS from scratch might be a highly educational experience, if you approach it from the right perspective.

Answer (score 2):

**Raw RSA is not a signature scheme**. It is only a component of a signature scheme. Actual signature or encryption schemes based on RSA also include **[padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Padding_schemes)**: instead of applying the raw RSA operation (*m* ↦ *m*<sup>*d*</sup> mod *n* or *m* ↦ *m*<sup>*e*</sup> mod *n*) to the message, it is applied to the concatenation of some padding text and the message. This padding has two main roles:

- It ensures that the RSA operation is not applied to a number that is too small. This prevents a number of mathematical relations from breaking the security of the use of RSA, the simplest being that if you compute *m*<sup>*e*</sup> mod *n* with both *m* and *e* small, no modulo reduction actually takes place.
- It ensures that the RSA operation is never applied twice to the same message. For encryption, this prevents an attacker from breaking the message by brute force (trying every possible plaintext). For signatures, this prevents a number of mathematical relations from arising when related messages are signed.

For more in-depth information about the role of padding, see [Is RSA of a random nonce with no padding safe?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/is-rsa-of-a-random-nonce-with-no-padding-safe) [Does RSA padding have to be unpredictable if the payload is?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/does-rsa-padding-have-to-be-unpredictable-if-the-payload-is) [Is RSA padding needed for single recipient, one-time, unique random message?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/is-rsa-padding-needed-for-single-recipient-one-time-unique-random-message)

There are two common padding schemes for RSA signatures: RSA-PSS and RSA-PKCS1.5. Both are defined by the [PKCS #1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS1) document which defines RSA. I will not explain them here, read the [PKCS #1 document](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf) for their definition. Both methods require that the message be first [hashed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) with a cryptographic digest function such as [SHA-256 or SHA-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) (or their predecessor [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)). Thus an actual RSA signature of an arbitrary¹ message looks like this:

```
RSA(key, message) = RSA_operation(key, padding ++ hash(message))
```

The hash compresses the relevant information about the message (namely, whether a purported message is equal to the genuine message) into a bounded size.
When doing encryption, such compression is not possible. To encrypt arbitrary-sized data with RSA, the usual method is to generate a random secret key (often called a session key), encrypt the actual message with that key and send the secret key encrypted with RSA. See [How can I use asymmetric encryption, such as RSA, to encrypt an arbitrary length of plaintext?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-can-i-use-asymmetric-encryption-such-as-rsa-to-encrypt-an-arbitrary-length)

¹ 
<sub>Technically, there are limits, but you won't run into them in practice: SHA-1 and SHA-256 can run up to 2<sup>61</sup>-1 bytes, SHA-512 up to 2<sup>125</sup>-1 bytes.</sub>