# Seeking lightweight encryption - shareable between Delphi & C

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, c

I want to encrypt a text file in Delphi & decrypt it, line by line, in C on an embedded system which does not have much RAM (so, only one line in RAM at a time).

FOSS must be available for both Delphi & C; nothign too huge, preferably a single file for each. No messing about wth key files, the kay & salt will be hard coded into the applciatioon.

I am seeking "just good enough" "security through obscurity". Enough to deter a causual hacker. The actual embedded device will be behind a physical lock & key.

[Verdict] I will go with either TEA or AES (tbd). I will split the functionality into two parts: 1) decrypt into a plain text file, 2) parse that as an INI file and if I hit memory problems then change to a `line_1=data_1, line_2=data_2` format.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symmetric-key encryption is very light weight,  I am not sure why memory/cpu this would be a concern, even on a cheap micro-controller.  Perhaps 30 years ago this was a worry,  but not in twenty-twelve.

I like AES-128 in CCM mode with a random IV.  If you don't know what that means, you probably shouldn't be implementing a crypto system. Encryption isn't some magic wand that protects you from attack,  a lot can go wrong.  Good cryptographers are hard to come by.

Comment: AES is standard, open, well-described, and available in enough libraries to make one blue in the face enumerating them for both Delphi and C.

Answer (score 1):

Use GPG.  [Don't roll your own!](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2210/971)  If you try to implement your own crypto, odds are good you will get something wrong.

If you are really, truly hardcoding the key in the application, I hope you realize that this is thoroughly insecure.  It's basically just security theater.  If that's what you want, have you considered [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)?