# .7z encrypted archive, how much is secure?

Tags: encryption, usb

I have a standard USB where i store secret info into a .7z encrypted archive with a 40 digit password (with upper case, numbers, special characters), I would know how safe  is it against FBI for example. I mean if FBI take my Usb with the encrypted archive can they crack my password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How secure is 7z encryption?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100650/how-secure-is-7z-encryption). Also Is [7-Zip's AES encryption just as secure as TrueCrypt's version?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29375/is-7-zips-aes-encryption-just-as-secure-as-truecrypts-version).