# How to encrypt email attachment?

Tags: encryption, email

I need to send 10 accounts login data via email, if i send it to a mac user a make an encrypted .dmg file, but as far as I know windows needs a third party app to open .dmg files.

Is it possible to make a .iso with password protection?
Is .rar or .zip file password protection safe?

Comment: What data? do you mean username + password. If you send this in a password protected file, how are you sending the password to that file?

Comment: Is Excel file with 10 account inside. I can send password to open the file via phone. I edited my question

Comment: Yea that sounds OK, a password protected .zip should be ok. I think a .7z can work on Mac and Windows.

Comment: You are essentially asking about how to encrypt files. That you want to sent this encrypted files then with email is just an unimportant detail. Thus possible duplicate of [Are password-protected ZIP files secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35818/are-password-protected-zip-files-secure), [How secure is 7z encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100650/how-secure-is-7z-encryption) and various others.

Answer (score 0):

It as everytime depends on the password too. A password protected .zip file should be fine. Another option would be to create a vera crypt file you can send via E-Mail if its small enough , too.

Comment: There are different types of zip encriptions and some of them are **not** fine at all!

Comment: Wasn't sure about that , thanks for the comment. But truecrypt files should work

Comment: when given the choice I would chose something like rar or 7z, one of the compression files that have been shown to be hard to brake. Even better would be something like pgp / gpg but thats a whole different toolchain.