# Crack 7Z password if I also have the original file

Tags: passwords, zip

Some of my files have been encrypted by ransomware. I can find some backup of files (unfortunately not all of them). Can I find the password of the 7Z zipped+encrypted files if I also have some of the original files?

Comment: If the files were encrypted using a pre-2019 version of 7zip, there may be hope.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100650/how-secure-is-7z-encryption/233813#233813 for more info.

Comment: Do you have the ransomware payload by any chance? Maybe submit it to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload)?

Comment: 1) Do you know anything about the password, for example its length and the characters used in it? 2) Some ransomware has been cracked and the decryption is publically available.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

7z uses AES-256 with the CBC mode of operation for encryption. Since AES in CBC mode is resistant to [known-plaintext attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) ( The CBC mode has greater security than KPA, it has [Ind-CPA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87033/18298)), having the original files will not assist you in cracking the key/password used for encryption.

mti2935 and Adam Katz point out that 7z used a broken IV generation mechanism up till 2019. While detrimental to secrecy of the encrypted data, as far as I can tell, it only leaks information about the plaintext. I'm not a cryptographer and can't state this authoritatively, but I don't think the weak IV enables attacks against AES that would allow recovery of the key/password faster than brute force. (Edit: Someone with sufficient cryptographic knowledge [has commented](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/255489/crack-7z-password-if-i-also-have-the-original-file/255490#comment525997_255490), confirming that the attack on weak IVs is not a key finding attack.)

Comment: AES is pretty strong, but 7zip's AES implementation has had at least one [vulnerability](https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1087848040583626753.html) identified in the past (it was a bad [RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation "random number generator")).

Comment: 1) (Edited) The link of @AdamKatz is problematic see also ;[7zip : Why does encrypting the same file with AES-256 not give the same output?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/77548/18298). The bug cleaned, however, one cannot apply a known-plaintext attack to the CBC mode. See the canonical question on Crypto [Why is CBC with predictable IV considered insecure against chosen-plaintext attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3883/18298) what you can do with this.

Comment: 2) The attack on weak/predictable IV is not a key finding attack. If the keys are the same for each file then even [AES-128 is secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76738/has-aes-128-been-fully-broken/76746#76746). And in the case of AES-256, the multi-target attack will fail, too. Even for AES-128, multi-target attack is far beyond OP. They should wait until the key is leaked, some attackers leaks after some time.

Comment: Also, note that AES is a primitive. To talk about KPA,Ind-CPA, Ind-CCA, etc, you need a mode of operation. It is better to say 7Zip uses AES in CBC mode and CBC-mode is [CPA-secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87033/18298)