# OpenVPN cipher mode of operation: CFB vs CFB1 vs CFB8

Tags: encryption, cryptography, vpn, cipher-selection, openvpn

I'm trying to understand the possible settings for the `cipher` in OpenVPN and somehow rank them security wise.

Right now I'm stuck at differentiating the modes of operation `CFB`, `CFB1` and `CFB8`. How do they differ in terms of security.

What advantages/disadvantages does one have over the other?

For instance, if I have the following cipher suites to chose from:

```
AES-128-CBC  (128 bit key, 128 bit block)
AES-128-CFB  (128 bit key, 128 bit block, TLS client/server mode only)
AES-128-CFB1  (128 bit key, 128 bit block, TLS client/server mode only)
AES-128-CFB8  (128 bit key, 128 bit block, TLS client/server mode only)
AES-128-GCM  (128 bit key, 128 bit block, TLS client/server mode only)
AES-128-OFB  (128 bit key, 128 bit block, TLS client/server mode only)
```

I'd rank them, only considering their security and robustness:

```
AES-128-GCM 
AES-128-CFB(1,8)
AES-128-OFB
AES-128-CBC
```

Am I right in doing so? Is it possible to define a difference between the three `CFB` modes in terms of security?

Comment: The CFB modes are different in terms of error recovery: see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/cipher-feedback-mode for details.

Comment: Thank you, that clarified a lot. Is my general assumption with the `GCM > CFB > OFB > CBC` correct?

Comment: In general, perhaps. They vary in suitability for different purposes, and I'm not confident to state an order given a use case I'm not particularly familiar with. Someone with more knowledge of how OpenVPN works internally may be able to though.

Comment: For some general remarks on the different modes, see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/27780/.